# How to show name of predicted tags

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am working on tag prediction. Here is some part of code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.00009, max_features=200000, tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(), ngram_range=(1,3))
X_train_multilabel = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train['question'])
X_test_multilabel = vectorizer.transform(X_test['question'])
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=0.00001, penalty='l2'))
clf.fit(X_train_multilabel, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_multilabel)
```

I am getting y_pred as a sparse matrix with 1's and 0's.Now I need to know how to predict the name of the tag.I was working with 1000 tags.So y_pred has 1000  columns.How can i know which column represents which tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the class_labels, it should be an array with length 1000.

Once you get that list,

`tags = ['cat', 'dogs', ...]` # len 1000

Then, you can just select those tags from your `y_pred`,

`tag_y = [tags[i] if y_pred[i] == 1 for i in range(1000)]`